# Help! What kind of bug is this?

Tags: species-identification

Please help identify this little bug and how I make them go away.

[image]

Comment: Where did you find it? Is it a pest? How many do you have? Where do you live (country, type of ecosystem)? What is the approximate size? Any other info (behaviour, what they feed on, etc..)

Comment: If you can get a clear photo showing the antennae it would help; at the moment I suspect family Anobiidae (order Coleoptera: beetles I'm sure of), but seeing the antennal segmentation (we can't with this photo) would help with my suspicions.